# Android Google Map API v 2 Black white screen loaded on signed apk

Tags: android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I am loading google maps on android devices success fully but when i signed the android build with my keystone app  show black screen on map with zoom and my location buttons

Comment: Create Global Realese.keystore  api key  for map by exporting the app.

Answer (score 0):

Say for example your apk name is App and you are signing and creating a keystore for App.apk 
ie App.keystore will be created in some drive location.Let's consider it in D drive.

step 2:

Now locate to jdk in C drive(Considering for windows and assigning C drive)

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore D:\App.keystore -alias App
So it will create SHA-1 finger print.